# ACF confidence intervals in R vs python: why are they different?

Tags: python, r, statistics, time-series

When I use the `acf` function in R it plots horizontal lines that represent the confidence interval (95% by default) for the autocorrelations at various lags:
[image: R ACF]

However, when I use `statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf` in python I see a curved confidence interval based on a more sophisticated computation:
[image: python ACF]

Notice that in the R version, the lags up through lag 25 are considered significant. For the same data, in the python version, only the lags up through 20 are considered significant.

What is the difference between these two methods, and which one should I trust more? Can someone explain the theory of the non-constant confidence interval computed by `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf`?

I know I can reproduce the R horizontal lines by simply plotting something like `y=[+/-]1.96 / np.sqrt(len(data))`.  However, I'd like to understand the fancy curved confidence interval.

Comment: Just as a note, these are just the _default_ behaviours. 

You can get python's `statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf` to plot the constant (white noise assumption) confidence interval by including the optional argument `bartlett_confint=False`, 

and you can get R's `acf()` to plot the nonconstant (moving average assumption) confidence interval with the argument `ci.type='ma'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has been shown that the autocorrelation coefficient `r(k)` follows a Gaussian distribution with variance `Var(r(k))`.

As you have found, in R, the variance is simply calculated as `Var(r(k)) = 1/N` for all `k`. While, in python, the variance is calculated using Bartlett’s formula, where `Var(r(k)) = 1/N (1 + 2(r(1)^2+r(2)^2+...+r(k-1)^2))`. This results in the first increasing, then flattening confidence level shown above.

Source code of ACF variances in python:

```
varacf = np.ones(nlags + 1) / nobs
varacf[0] = 0
varacf[1] = 1. / nobs
varacf[2:] *= 1 + 2 * np.cumsum(acf[1:-1]**2)
```

These two distinct formulas are based on different assumptions. The former assumes an i.i.d process and `r(k) = 0` for all `k != 0`, while the later assumes a MA process with order of `k-1` where ACF "cuts tail" after lag `k`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! However, is there finally any difference when using the R or python implementation? Or others said: Does it matter that it is curved at the beginning? Despite from that it seems they provide the same results.

Comment: How a bounded random variable r(k) can be normally distributed....

Comment: I would like to understand the assumption “MA process with order of k-1 where ACF ’cuts tail’ after lag k”. Does someone have a recommendation for where to look?

Comment: In particular, is it generally true that the nonconstant conf ints version (Bartlett’s formula) is more justified when the data have intrinsic time-dependence?

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to the theory part of this (which might be better on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com)), but maybe useful ... ?

If you go to the [documentation page for statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html) it gives you an option to [browse the source code](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/stattools.html#acf).  The code there is:

```
varacf = np.ones(nlags + 1) / nobs
varacf[0] = 0
varacf[1] = 1. / nobs
varacf[2:] *= 1 + 2 * np.cumsum(acf[1:-1]**2)
interval = stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.) * np.sqrt(varacf)
confint = np.array(lzip(acf - interval, acf + interval))
```

In contrast, the [R source code for plot.acf](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/acf.R#L135) shows

```
clim0 <- if (with.ci) qnorm((1 + ci)/2)/sqrt(x$n.used) else c(0, 0)
```

where `ci` is the confidence level (default=0.95).

Comment: Thanks Ben -- yes, I found that as well but still wonder about the theory and about which method is "better".